# User confirmation email not being received by hotmail?

Tags: users, emails

Has anyone experienced any issues with hotmail not receiving user confirmation emails? Our site is set up on a staging server and confirmation emails seem to work for all other email addresses we have tested apart from hotmail. Can't see anything in the logs that would suggest any problem.

Comment: And they aren't in your junk folder?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was being rejected by Hotmail. Not appearing in junk mail being bounced at server level. Switched to using SMTP and problem solved. Possibly due to over testing with emails to the same address.

Comment: Related, this is a list of things you can do to help guarantee better email delivery: http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/